# Multi-line logging in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.3.5 and the logging module to log information to a local file (from different threads). There are cases where I'd like to output some additional information, without knowing exactly what that information will be (e.g. it might be one single line of text or a dict).

What I'd like to do is add this additional information to my log file, after the log record has been written. Furthermore, the additional info is only necessary when the log level is error (or higher).

Ideally, it would look something like:

```
2014-04-08 12:24:01 - INFO     - CPU load not exceeded
2014-04-08 12:24:26 - INFO     - Service is running
2014-04-08 12:24:34 - ERROR    - Could not find any active server processes
Additional information, might be several lines.
Dict structured information would be written as follows:
key1=value1
key2=value2
2014-04-08 12:25:16 - INFO     - Database is responding
```

Short of writing a custom log formatter, I couldn't find much which would fit my requirements. I've read about filters and contexts, but again this doesn't seem like a good match.

Alternatively, I could just write to a file using the standard I/O, but most of the functionality already exists in the Logging module, and moreover it's thread-safe.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. If a custom log formatter is indeed necessary, any pointers on where to start would be fantastic.

Comment: As @BorrajaX mentions in his answer below, multi-line logging is a bad practice. I would instead recommend you implement logging JSON structures and optionally parse them out as YAML for easy of reading locally. I've not done this in Python, but I have in Node and I've found it to be the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just add `\n`  symbols to the output text.

Comment: If I define a log formatter as `lf = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s - %(message)s\\n%(detail)s')` and define a `FileHandler` to write the logging to a file, the output will contain the `\n` instead of being converted to a line break.

Comment: Follow "The Logging Cookbook". Use `str.format()` style for template instead of the default %-based style - then it will respect special symbols.

Answer (score 24):

Keeping in mind that many people consider a multi-line logging message a bad practice (understandably so, since if you have a log processor like DataDog or Splunk which are very prepared to handle single line logs, multi-line logs will be very hard to parse), you can play with the `extra` parameter and use a custom formatter to append *stuff* to the message that is going to be shown (take a look to the usage of 'extra' in the logging package [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.debug)).

```
import logging

class CustomFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'dct') and len(record.dct) > 0:
            for k, v in record.dct.iteritems():
                record.msg = record.msg + '\n\t' + k + ': ' + v
        return super(CustomFilter, self).filter(record)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    extra_logger = logging.getLogger('extra_logger')
    extra_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    extra_logger.addFilter(CustomFilter())
    logging.debug("Nothing special here... Keep walking")
    extra_logger.info("This shows extra",
                      extra={'dct': {"foo": "bar", "baz": "loren"}})
    extra_logger.debug("You shouldn't be seeing this in the output")
    extra_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    extra_logger.debug("Now you should be seeing it!")
```

That code outputs:

```
DEBUG:root:Nothing special here... Keep walking
INFO:extra_logger:This shows extra
        foo: bar
        baz: loren
DEBUG:extra_logger:Now you should be seeing it!
```

I still recommend calling the `super`'s `filter` function in your custom filter, mainly because that's the function that decides whether showing the message or not (for instance, if your logger's level is set to `logging.INFO`, and you log something using `extra_logger.debug`, that message shouldn't be seen, as shown in the example above)

Answer (score 4):

i'm using a simple line splitter in my smaller applications:

```
for line in logmessage.splitlines():
            writemessage = logtime + " - " + line + "\n"
            logging.info(str(writemessage))
```

Note that this is not thread-safe and should probably only be used in log-volume logging applications.

However you can output to log almost anything, as it will preserve your formatting. I have used it for example to output JSON API responses formatted using: `json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I made a small typo when defining my LogFormatter string: by accidentally escaping the newline character, I wrongly assumed that writing multi-line output to a log file was not possible.

Cheers to @Barafu for pointing this out (which is why I assigned him the correct answer).

Here's the sample code:

```
import logging
lf = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s - %(message)s\n%(detail)s')
lh = logging.FileHandler(filename=r'c:\temp\test.log')
lh.setFormatter(lf)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(lh)
log.debug('test', extra={'detail': 'This is a multi-line\ncomment to test the formatter'})
```

The resulting output would look like this:

```
DEBUG    - test
This is a multi-line
comment to test the formatter
```

### Caveat:

If there is no detail information to log, and you pass an empty string, the logger will still output a newline. Thus, the remaining question is: how can we make this conditional?

One approach would be to update the logging formatter before actually logging the information, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6888270/3165737).