# How do I format error message and stack when logging an Exception in python3 logging setup with dictconfig?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm using `logging.config.dictconfig()` and my formatter is:

```
'formatters': {
                'logfileFormat': {
                    'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s'
                }
            }
```

When there's an exception, I would like the formatter to show the error message, as well as print out the exec_info. How do I alter the `format` to do this? Or do I need to implement my own formatter in code, and reference it here?

Comment: Isn't something like `logger.exception("Error occurred: %s", e)` enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but calling `logger.exception(e)` already adds the stack trace and error message.

(While `logger.error(e)` only shows the message)

See this POC script:

```py
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'logfileFormat': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s'
            }
        },
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'logfileFormat',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # Default is stderr
            },
        },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # root logger
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
            },
        }
    })

def foo():
    logging.info("Normal stuff")
    logging.warning("More stuff")

    try:
        # ... something causing an exception ...
        raise Exception("Something something, Exception")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

    try:
        raise Exception("The stacktrace of this is surpressed")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    logging.info("More normal stuff")

foo()
```

Which results in the following output:

```
2020-07-26 20:54:27,621 root        : INFO Normal stuff
2020-07-26 20:54:27,621 root        : WARNING More stuff
2020-07-26 20:54:27,621 root        : ERROR Something something, Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sol.py", line 34, in foo
    raise Exception("Something something, Exception")
Exception: Something something, Exception
2020-07-26 20:54:27,622 root        : ERROR The stacktrace of this is surpressed
2020-07-26 20:54:27,622 root        : INFO More normal stuff
```

I fail to see in what way your existing **formatter** needs to be changed.

If you wanted your stack trace to be **indented** or otherwise **formatted** differently, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22937976/11815682) for creating a **custom formatter**.

Answer (score 1):

logging automatically adds the traceback to your message if you use `log.exception(e)`.

If you want to log the traceback with other logging levels, you can use the `exc_info=True` kwarg like `log.error("message", exc_info=True)`.

You don't need to modify the formatter for the traceback to show up.