# How to Write Headers in Log File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have made a log file. Now i want to print a Headers in log file. SO that one can identify what's that column is for.

I have provided the code i have written.

```
def logger(type_of_message, msg, ticket_no):   #This will create records/log in app.log file. And can be used for debuging too. 
    log_file = str(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')) + '.log'
    if(type_of_message == 'INFO' or 'Info'):
        logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {'ticket_no': '%s' % (ticket_no)})
        logging.basicConfig(filename = log_file, filemode = 'a', level = logging.INFO, format =  '%(ticket_no)s -  %(asctime)s -  %(name)s  -  %(levelname)s - %(message)s')    
        logger.info(msg)
    elif(type_of_message == 'ERROR' or 'Error'): 
        logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {'ticket_no': '%s'%(ticket_no)}) 
        logging.basicConfig(filename = 'app.log', filemode = 'a', level = logging.ERROR,  format  = '%(ticket_no)s - %(asctime)s -  %(name)s  -  %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        logger.info(msg)
```

I  want to print it like this:

```
TICKET NO       DATE        TIME         NAME    USER   MESSAGE

INC0010265 -  2019-06-25 20:41:54,286 -  log  -  INFO - Mail Send Succesfully
INC0010265 -  2019-06-25 20:41:56,271 -  log  -  INFO - INC0010265  Ticket Update Succesfully
INC0010265 -  2019-06-25 20:41:56,271 -  log  -  INFO - -----Ticket Closed-----
```

Comment: `with open('file.log') as f: f.write('some text')`

Comment: You shouldn't call `logging.basicConfig` more than once for one program. Your whole use of the `logging` is a bit off. you should read the [how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: The first answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847862/how-to-change-the-format-of-logged-messages-temporarily-in-python can solve your problem!

Comment: @hoefling But ut will just add thse thing only one file as you can see i am creating file for each day..

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks But I want add those header(TICKET NO , DATE , TIME , NAME , USER,  MESSAGE) only as i am getting the rest in output

Comment: @Tomerikoo Can you tell me How will i use it only once in that function  l

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% what you're asking for but is closest I can think of.

First of all, you shouldn't call `basicConfig` more than once for the same program. It actually simply does nothing...

Also, you kinda losing the `logging` power by defining your own function that checks the message type. It looks funny to call `logger.info` for an error message. What you **should** do instead is use `Handler`s. Check out this code:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log_file = str(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')) + '.log'

error_handler = logging.FileHandler("app.log")
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
info_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(info_handler)
logger.addHandler(error_handler)

header_formatter = logging.Fomatter('%(message)s')
default_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s -  %(name)s  -  %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

error_handler.setFormatter(header_formatter)
info_handler.setFormatter(header_formatter)

logger.error("DATE\t\tTIME\t\tNAME\t\tUSER\t\tTICKET NO\tMESSAGE")

error_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)
info_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter )
```

A few explanations:

- We are using two handlers: `error_handler` and `info_handler` to direct different types of messages to different files. **NOTE** that in this way error messages will be also in the info file.
- We set the `logger`'s level to the minimal between them (in this case `INFO`) and add to it our handlers.
- Then we use special `formatter`s to the header and regular messages. We first assign to both handlers the header formatter. We then print the header (using `logger.error` so it will go to both logs). And then set the handlers with the regular formatter.
- All messages logged from this point on will be in the regular format.

2nd **NOTE**: I couldn't find a way to add a field to the fomat as what you tried to acheive for `ticket_no`. As you can see I moved the column to be before the messgae so simply add the `ticke_no` in the start of your message. What you can do is for example:

```py
def log_msg(logger, type_of_message, msg, ticket_no):
    msg = "{}\t{}".format(ticket_no, msg)
    if(type_of_message == 'INFO' or 'Info'):
        logger.info(msg)
    elif(type_of_message == 'ERROR' or 'Error'): 
        logger.error(msg)
```