# Append environment variables in log format in Python

Tags: python, logging, environment-variables

I have a Rabbitmq consumer that gets messages from another service with a unique_id. I need to set some environment variables which prints in every log within that process message block.

```
import logging
import os

LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-7s %(message)s  : unique_id  : os.getenv("unique_id","1")'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=LOG_FORMAT)
```

also updating os var before message process block:

```
os.environ["unique_id"] = new_unique_id
```

however, with the above code log format is not taking the latest value of unique_id. It always prints 1. Seems it only takes value while initialization.

I only want to append unique_id for each log message in that particular block with updated unique_id. 
As it is a very big project so I don't want to append this to each log manually. I want to use a log format here.

New to the python, so not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, the `LOG_FORMAT` will be fixed to the time when logger is configured. If you just want to prefix the logs, why not add it to your log message instead? `logging.info(os.getenv("unique_id", "1") + "your message here")` or create a function to wrap around logging calls?

or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6888270/1509809)

Comment: you can define your own values that you can use in the logging format. you could also use a logging adapter or filter for your particular logger, which sets the corresponding extra value. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558552/how-do-i-add-custom-field-to-python-log-format-string

you could also use a mapped diagnostic context in your code, in java this is common practice, in python you'd have e.g. https://pypi.org/project/mdc/.

Comment: ...the MDC will allow you to temporarily set contextual values (your unique id) that you can use in your log messages within a given code block.