# logging formatter with variable

Tags: python, logging

I would like to add a variable from a for loop to a the logging formatter. It seemed quite intuitive to achieve this by replacing the variable in the `format` string before resetting the `logging.basicConfig`:

```
import logging
import os
a = ['foo', 'bar']

for i in a:
    format = f'{i}: %(asctime)s %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'test.log',
                        level = logging.INFO,
                        format = format)
    logging.info('this is a test')
```

However, the output is:

```
foo: 2020-10-16 21:51:26,226 this is a test
foo: 2020-10-16 21:51:26,226 this is a test
```

So I guess that the basicConfig cannot be overwritten?

How could I achieve that the output is:

```
foo: 2020-10-16 21:51:26,226 this is a test
bar: 2020-10-16 21:51:26,226 this is a test
```

I am aware that I can easily add the variable in the message part, but that leads to a lot of unnecessary typing.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Following the discussion on the thread mentioned in the comments, I managed to get a nice solution. The trick is to assign a logger and set the string with `.setFormatter` inside the loop.

```
import logging
import os
a = ['foo', 'bar']

logger = logging.getLogger()  # Logger
logger_handler = logging.StreamHandler()  # Handler for the logger
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
logger.setLevel('INFO')

for f in a:
    logger_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(f'{f}: ' '%(message)s'))
    logging.info('this is a test')
```

This correctly produces:

```
foo: this is a test
bar: this is a test
```

Comment: Is this of any help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847862/how-to-change-the-format-of-logged-messages-temporarily-in-python

Comment: `basicConfig` can't be "reset". Once a logger is configured it does nothing. It will not change an existing logging configuration. That is why only the first iteration of the loop has the wanted effect.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. See the edit how I solved it.